# How to write exactly two lines in EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have created a `TextInputEditText` that allows you to take simple notes.

I have set `maxlines="2"` and `inputType="textMultiLine"` to write up to two lines.

However, when you start writing and there are two lines, the size of the `view` is set to fit the size of two lines, but you can continue to write text.

In other words, you can write more than 2 lines of text.

How can I solve this?

---

**Normal**

[image]

**Write two lines (Increase view size to fit up to two lines)**

[image]

**Write more than two lines(scrollable)**

[image]

**XML***

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    style="@style/Custom.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/hint_memo"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:maxLines="2" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately maxLines corresponds to the **outer height** of the Edit area not the actual text inside
You might want to use **TextWatcher** method to limit typing to whatever amount of lines you want

```
    textInput.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
        }

        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
        }
        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
            // find how many rows it cointains
            val editTextRowCount = textInput.lineCount
            if (editTextRowCount > 2) {
                textInput.text?.delete(textInput.selectionEnd - 1,textInput.selectionStart)
            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: I just found out that it corresponds to the outer height of the `Edittext area`, not the `actual text`... Thank you